# How to modify a dictionary from a csv file in raw python?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I have a file that looks like this, I want to get data from this file so that I can create a dictionary that takes the neighboruhood names as keys, with its values being ID, Population, and Low rate.

```
ID    Neighbourhood Name               Population   Low rate 
1     East Billin-Pickering                43567    1000
2     North Eglinton-Silverstone-Ajax      33098    9087
3     Wistle-dong Lock                     25009    6754
4     Squarion-Staion                      10000    8790
5     Doki doki lolo                        6789    2315
```

The output should look something like this (IF THE DICTIONARY I AM GIVEN IS EMPTY)

```
 {'East Billin-Pickering':
  {'id': 1, 'population': 43567, 'low_rate': 1000,
  'North Eglinton-Silverstone-Ajax':
  {'id': 2, 'population': 33098, 'low_rate': 9087},
  'Wistle-dong Lock':
  {'id': 3, 'population': 25009, 'low_rate': 6754},
  'Squarion-Staion':
  {'id': 4, 'population': 10000, 'low_rate': 8790},
  'Doki doki lolo':
  {'id': 5, 'population': 6789, 'low_rate': 2315}}
```

The file is already open, and I am also given a dictionary that may or may not have given values in it. How would I update that dictionary using data from the file?

Can somebody give me hints? I'm so confused.

I have no idea on how to start this. I know I have loop through the file, and will have to use strip() and split() methods at one point. I'm not sure how to actually get the values themselves, and modify them into a dictionary.

```
def get_data(data: dict, file: TextIO) -> None:
    """
    """
    opened = file.read().strip()
    for line in file:
        words = line.split(SEP)
        income_data = tuple(opened[POP], opened[LI_COL])
        data[LI_NBH_NAME_COL] = tuple(opened[ID_COL], income_data)
# Constants I'm using are:
SEP = ','
POP = 2
LI_COL = 3
ID_COL = 0
```

I'm trying to write an answer that does not use any imports, even the CSV import, mostly for understanding. I want to write a program that doesn't use imports so that I can better understand what's happening before I start importing csv.

How would this work?

Answer (score 2):

If you can install 3rd party library you can use pandas as following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter="\t") # Set delimiter and file name to your specific file 
data = data.set_index("Neighbourhood Name")
final_dict = data.to_dict(orient="index")
```

Final dict now contains:

```
{
   "East Billin-Pickering":{
      "ID":1,
      "Population":43567,
      "Low rate ":1000
   },
   "North Eglinton-Silverstone-Ajax":{
      "ID":2,
      "Population":33098,
      "Low rate ":9087
   },
   "Wistle-dong Lock":{
      "ID":3,
      "Population":25009,
      "Low rate ":6754
   },
   "Squarion-Staion":{
      "ID":4,
      "Population":10000,
      "Low rate ":8790
   },
   "Doki doki lolo":{
      "ID":5,
      "Population":6789,
      "Low rate ":2315
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'myCSV.csv'

def read_csv(filename):
    return pd.read_csv(filename).to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv` and `DictReader`. For example:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

would print:

```
{'ID': '1', 'Neighbourhood Name': 'East Billin-Pickering', 'Population': '43567', 'Low rate': '1000'}
{'ID': '2', 'Neighbourhood Name': 'North Eglinton-Silverstone-Ajax', 'Population': '33098', 'Low rate': '9087'}
{'ID': '3', 'Neighbourhood Name': 'Wistle-dong Lock', 'Population': '25009', 'Low rate': '6754'}
{'ID': '4', 'Neighbourhood Name': 'Squarion-Staion', 'Population': '10000', 'Low rate': '8790'}
{'ID': '5', 'Neighbourhood Name': 'Doki doki lolo', 'Population': '6789', 'Low rate': '2315'}
```

So, with that you can construct any dictionary you want. In your specific case it could look something like:

```
import csv

result_dict = {}

with open('input.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        result_dict[row["Neighbourhood Name"]] = {
            "ID": row.get("id"),
            "population": row.get("population"),
            "low_rate": row.get("low_rate")
        }
```

That should give you the dictionary you wanted. Hope this helps.